# "Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int)" Error

Tags: android

When I tried to googleMap.moveCamera using bound, I got error `Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int)`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int)` instead. It tells `newLatLngBoudnd()` width and height of the layout. In my case:

```
...
int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
int padding = 50;

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding));
...
```

*Ref: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/issues/10*